# Group Elements Question using the identity element and exponents

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

If $a$ is a group element and $a^6=e$, what are the possibilities for for $|a|$? 
Would it be correct to look at all the exponents up to $6$ for a and take their individual elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $a^6=e$, then there's an upper bound of $6$ for $|a|$ by the definition of the order of an element. So, we just need to check what other values are possible. Have you proved a proposition in class yet which says that $a^n=e$ if and only if $|a|$ divides $n$? If not I encourage you to try and prove it yourself. In your particular case, this proposition implies that $|a|\in\{1,2,3,6\}=A$ as $A$ is the set of divisors of $6$.